# Has anyone resharper 5 with xunit running?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, xunit.net

I installed the latest binaries from

http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/35006

and followed the suggestions from

http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=79225

because the [linked installation instructions](http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/29279) are out of date (basically there are more libs to copy to the plugins dir)

Now my resharper shows the plugin in the Plugins diialog, but I have no testing functionality at all. Not even Testdriven.NET seems to recognize the xunit tests (even if I "reinstalled" them via the xunit.installer.exe).

What a drag! Anyone can give me a hand here?

--Jan

Comment: could you specify which dll was missed?
xunit.dll* xunitcontrib.runner.resharper.provider.5.1.pdb*
xunit.runner.utility.dll* xunitcontrib.runner.resharper.runner.5.1.dll*
xunitcontrib.runner.resharper.provider.5.1.dll* xunitcontrib.runner.resharper.runner.5.1.pdb* I am still unable to run the tests.

Comment: sorry, this thread is ancient. no idea what exactly was wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A I guess, I just forgot one of the dlls.
Now I have got it working.